# Calculate PHP date_diff and save to ACF Field during post creation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I am facing the following challenge right now, if someone could help met out I would really appreciate it.

I have a WooCommerce store which automatically creates a new post after every order which is completed. These orders are saved into a Custom Post Type, with the order details in an ACF repeater field. For this function I used the undermentioned code.

Right now I want to add an extra function to my code which calculates the days between the order date and today. The order date is equal to the published date of the stored post. So in fact the calculation should be based on the published date and today. After the calculation is made, I want to store the days into an ACF numbers field.

For example if someone ordered a product on the first of november and today it is the 24th of november, the outcome should be 23.

The code I use right now.

```
//Create post

function create_post_after_order( $order_id ) {
  if (  $order_id instanceof WC_Order ){
    return;
  }

//Find items based on orderID
     
  $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
  $order_items = $order->get_items(); 

//Loop through items
    
    foreach ( $order_items as $item_id => $item_data ) {
    $product_ids[]       = $item_data->get_product_id();
    $product_names[]     = $item_data->get_name();
    $product_quantities[] = $item_data->get_quantity(); 
    $ordeline_subtotals[]     = $item_data->get_subtotal(); 

    $product_details = $item_data->get_product();

    // Get the product price that customer paid
    $product_prices[]        = $product_details->get_price(); 

    //Get sale price (i.e discounted price, if it exists)
    $product_regular_price  = $product_details->get_sale_price(); 

    //Regular price.
    $product_sale_price     = $product_details->get_regular_price();
}

//Create actual post
    
    $new_post = array(
    'post_title' => "Order {$order_id}", 
    'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 
    'post_author' => $user_ID, 
    'post_type' => 'groeiproces', 
    'post_status' => 'publish',
  );    

  $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
    
//Connect ACF Fields

    $orderdetails_key = 'field_61645b866cbd6';
    $product_id_key = 'field_6166a67234fa3';
    $product_name_key = 'field_61645b916cbd7';
    $product_price_key = 'field_6166a68134fa4';
    $product_quantity_key = 'field_6165bd2101987';
    $ordeline_subtotal_key = 'field_6166a68934fa5';
    $product_id = $product_ids;
    $product_name = $product_names;
    $product_price = $product_prices;
    $product_quantity = $product_quantities;
    $ordeline_subtotal = $ordeline_subtotals;

//Save orderdata in ACF repeater field

foreach ($product_id as $index => $product_id) {
    $orderdetails_value[] = array(
    $product_id_key => $product_id, 
    $product_name_key => $product_name[$index],
    $product_price_key => $product_price[$index],
    $product_quantity_key => $product_quantity[$index],
    $ordeline_subtotal_key => $ordeline_subtotal[$index],
);
    update_field( $orderdetails_key, $orderdetails_value, $post_id );
}
    
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'create_post_after_order', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: How is `$user_ID` defined in this scope? Also where should the date_diff be in this code?  Can you comment that somewhere?

Comment: The shop is private so the user_id is defined by the current loggin in user. This user will be added to the post as post author. This gives me the possibility to only show the posts that are connected to the user in the frontend user dashboard. 

I thinks after the loop I should add the function to calculate the date_diff. Then I can use that parameter to save in the ACF field.

Comment: Which ACF field is the one that it should be stored to?  Since `$orderdetails_value` is an array, do you want to add another item in there or what?

Comment: No, it is another ACF Field. Which is not an array. The field name is 'datum', with field ID 'field_619e20f8a9763'.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the Order object in your function, you just need to add this at some point after you insert post.

```
$order_date = date_create( $order->get_date_created() );
$date_diff = date_diff( $order_date, date_create( date( 'Y-m-d' ) ) );

update_field( 'field_619e20f8a9763', $date_diff->days, $post_id );
```